# How to format the a long line in python where a function call returns multiple outputs and I have to receive them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

So I have the following line in python:

```py
for category in SomeLongClass.license_categories:
    data[f"Category {category}"], data[f"Category {category} Validity Date"], data[f"Category {category} Expiry Date"] = SomeLongClass.get_category_dates(text_lines=text_lines, category=category)
```

And as you can see this line is long and compromises on readability. I ran pylint on this file, and it just tells me that this line is long, but not how to remedy it. I tried googling it out, it says to just put a `\` and break in a new line, but isn't that going to compromise readability more in this case?

How to go about formatting this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way that my group at work would have done it: align the receiving variables, align the line continuations (not strictly PEP-8), and indent the RHS.

```
# Assign three return values to the desired variables.
data[f"Category {category}"],               \
data[f"Category {category} Validity Date"], \
data[f"Category {category} Expiry Date"] =  \
    SomeLongClass.get_category_dates(text_lines=text_lines, category=category)
```

Comment: Thanks @Prune. This did the trick! Got rid of Pylint error and is way more readable now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the line breaks. It should be

```
for category in SomeLongClass.license_categories:
    (data[f"Category {category}"], \
    data[f"Category {category} Validity Date"], \
    data[f"Category {category} Expiry Date"]) = SomeLongClass.get_category_dates(text_lines=text_lines, category=category)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning to different variables and then assign to those variables

```
for category in SomeLongClass.license_categories:
    a1, a2, a3 = SomeLongClass.get_category_dates(text_lines=text_lines,
                                                  category=category)
    data[f"Category {category}"] = a1
    data[f"Category {category} Validity Date"] = a2
    data[f"Category {category} Expiry Date"] = a3
```